# ConTeXt: math mode font size in startstops

Tags: context

Take a look at this simple document:

```tex
\definestartstop[test][style={\tfx}]
\showgrid

\startTEXpage[offset=.5mm]
  Let's take a look.

  Math without style: $\pi=3.1415...$.

  \starttest
    Math in startstop with style: $\pi=3.1415...$.
  \stoptest
\stopTEXpage
```

This document should be straightforward. Yet, I have an issue with it.

[image]

The font size in math mode has not been modified. How can I modify it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try either

```
\definestartstop[test][style=\small]
\showgrid

\startTEXpage[offset=.5mm]
  Let's take a look.

  Math without style: $\pi=3.1415 \ldots$.

  \starttest
    Math in startstop with style: $\pi=3.1415 \ldots$.
  \stoptest
\stopTEXpage
```

or even (I've heard this might be the default someday)

```
\enableexperiments[fonts.compact]

\definestartstop[test][style=\tfx]
\showgrid

\startTEXpage[offset=.5mm]
  Let's take a look.

  Math without style: $\pi=3.1415 \ldots$.

  \starttest
    Math in startstop with style: $\pi=3.1415 \ldots$.
  \stoptest
\stopTEXpage
```

Result in both cases:

[image: small with small math]

But perhaps, it is better to use `\switchtobodyfont[Xpt]` where `X` is the size you want. I guess it depends on what you do.